# Fetch only the records that were added in this week to a table in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

How can I fetch only the records that were added in this week to a table in Postgres? Please note that the table doesn't have any timestamp fields. Please let me know, in case of any possible ways of doing this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13768274/postgresql-how-to-find-any-changes-in-the-last-n-minutes

Comment: Is this a one time thing or you want to do this every week?

Comment: I want do this periodically, as I have to generate reports of the newly added data into the table.

Comment: If you don't have a column that stores date and time when that row has been added, then there is no way you can't get that information.